# Data not showing when changing Input to textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

This is my code to display code out of my database:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){

echo '<form action="details.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'" method="post">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$row['ID'].'">';
echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input name="title" value="' . $row['Title'] . '">' .'</td>' ;
echo '<td>' . '<input size=85 name="detail" value="' . $row['Detail'] . '" cols="85" rows="2">'.'</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['eventDate'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['dateAdded'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="submit" name="update" value="update" class="btn btn-default"> ' . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" class="btn btn-default"> ' . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

When I try to change the Inputs to `<textarea>`'s it stops showing the data from the database but only the text field. When I check Page Source it shows the data. How to format the fields like this:

```
echo '<td>' . '<textarea name="title" value="' . $row['Title'] . '">'. '</textarea>' .'</td>' ;
echo '<td>' . '<textarea size=85 name="detail" value="' . $row['Detail'] . '" cols="85" rows="2">'. '</textarea>' .'</td>';
```

Comment: Textareas don't have a `value` attribute. The content should go between the open and close tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textarea`s don't have a `value` attribute. Place the value between the opening and closing tags instead:

```
echo '<td><textarea name="title">'. $row['Title'] . '</textarea></td>' ;
echo '<td><textarea size=85 name="detail" cols="85" rows="2">'. $row['Detail'] .'</textarea></td>';
```

Comment: This worked.. I'm so embarassed that this was my problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad i could help

Comment: don't forget to escape your data with `htmlspecialchars($row['Title'], ENT_QUOTES);` else you might endup with all sorts of problems.

Comment: What do you mean Shujaat?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the text between textarea tags instead of adding value attribute

```
echo '<td>' . '<textarea name="title">'. $row['Title'] .'</textarea>' .'</td>' ;
```

Comment: The comment above helped still thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The general format for a text are field is `<textarea name="name" cols="width" rows="height" wrap="type"> </textarea>`
So there shouldn't be a value attribute. Something like this:
`echo '<td>' . '<textarea name="title">'. '</textarea>' .'</td>' ;`